# NSManagedObjectContext, best way to pass it around? Access it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a question regarding how to pass around `NSManagedObjectContext`. In my app, it seems like it's my `AppDelegate` that handles `NSManagedObjectContext`, so I shouldn't create other `NSManagedObjectContexts` in my other `ViewControllers`.

So the question is...

There is any convention or smart method to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I pass the NSManagedObjectContext is to simply have an iVar in each view controller you pass it to.  I usually modify the initialiser to include assignment, something like this....

MyNewViewController.h

```
 @interface MyNewViewController : UIViewController {
     NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
 }
 ...
```

MyNewViewController.m

```
@implementation MyNewViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil andContext:(NSManagedObjectContext *)ctx {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        managedObjectContext = ctx;
    }
    return self;
}

....
```

Then when you call the view controller, you simply use the modified initialiser. Like...

```
MyNewViewController *nv = [[MyNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyNewViewController" bundle:nil andContext:self.managedObjectContext];
```

Now you've got a reference to the managedObjectContext which you can use within your view controller.

Comment: Not in the view!  That would be a violation of MVC.  The views should know nothing about the model.  Put the ivar in the view controller.

Comment: Oh yes, and don't call your view controllers xyz**View** call the xyz**ViewController**.

Comment: Lol... I'd have thought the code example would have given away the fact I was talking about a view controller!  But I've modified it for correctness.

Comment: I see, that's a way to do it ^^ Thanks :)

Comment: I found another method, can anyone state the difference? `NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];`

Comment: @Sin Li:  Nothing wrong with that, but Simon's way involves a bit less typing in the long run.

Comment: There isn't much difference - you're still getting a reference to your MOC.  I prefer the way I stated because I can see when I instantiate a new view controller, whether it requires the MOC to be passed.  It really makes no odds though - the outcome would be the same.

Comment: The only difference here is that Apple's documentation states that you should not use the `NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];` approach. They explicitly call it out when reading through the Core Data docs. @Simon has the correct approach.